# cloud-init running on macos

Tags: terraform, esxi, cloud-init

I want to create few VMs in my homelab which is running on free ESXi. For this I'd like to use terraform. I've found [terraform-provider-esxi](https://github.com/josenk/terraform-provider-esxi) which requires [cloud-init-vmware-guestinfo](https://github.com/vmware/cloud-init-vmware-guestinfo) and that requires [cloud-init](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init). So my question is is it possible to run all of those scripts from MACos? If not is there some alternative? I can think of installing custom VM in mac (not preferred) or use some docker container that contains all libraries.

Thanks

Comment: `cloud-init` is something that runs inside your virtual machines; it's not something that would run directly on your Mac.

Comment: that wmvare script just needs that.. I believe it's trying to prepare image on my mac and then uploading it to esxi.